# Oracle Group by only one column but select many columns

Tags: oracle, aggregates

**Object types:**

Theatre_t  (tno:integer, nome:string, city:string, phone:string)

Star_t  (nome:string, gender:char(l), birthdate:date)
Stars_nt table of Star _t

Film_t  (filmno:integer, title:string, language:string,   director:string,
budget:float, stars stars_nt)

Show_t (film ref film_t, theatre ref theatre_t, startdate:date, enddate:date )

**Tables**

Theatres of theatre_t (tno primary key)

Films of film_t (filmno    primary key)
Nested table stars store as stars_ntb

Showing of show_t (film references films, theatre references theatres)

---

I need to get For each theatre, the title of film that played for the longest period.and Display the theatre name, city and the title of the film.

I tried many ways but i can not achieve it since in oracle sql we can not add columns to select which are not in the group by. I need to group by only theatre name and display the theatre name longest running movie title and city of the thetre.

Comment: What do you need to show if, for a given theatre, there are two (or more) films that are tied for "played for longest period"?

Comment: i need to display both films then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need the KEEP extension.

For example:  "Show me lowest salary per department" is easy

```
SQL> select deptno, min(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;
```

but now you want add WHO has that lowest salary as well, which gets you stuck

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, min(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

You can use the KEEP analytic clause to help out

```
 SQL> select
  2    deptno,
  3    min(sal),
  4    min(empno) keep ( dense_rank FIRST order by sal) empno,
  5    min(job) keep ( dense_rank FIRST order by sal)   job,
  6    min(ename) keep ( dense_rank FIRST order by sal) ename
  7  from emp
  8  group by deptno
  9  /

    DEPTNO   MIN(SAL)      EMPNO JOB       ENAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       1300       7934 CLERK     MILLER
        20        800       7369 CLERK     SMITH
        30        950       7900 CLERK     JAMES
```

Full set of tutorials on Analytic SQL including the above here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cjxYMxa1e4&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what if we need add another columns such as employee contact number as per your example. this gets complicated right?

Comment: only if copy/paste is complicated :-) I've added to the original answer